# Is there a simple(-ish) algorithm for drawing force-directed graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph, p5.js, force-layout

[image]

I'm trying to write a little graph visualizer in P5js but I can't find a simple(-ish) algorithm to follow.

I've found ways to do it with D3 and I've found some dense textbook snippets (like [this](http://cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf)) but I'm looking for something in between the two.

Can someone explain the simplest algorithm for drawing a graph (force-directed or otherwise) or point me to a good resource?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I literally just started [something similar](https://editor.p5js.org/JeromePaddick/sketches/bjA_UOPip).

It's fairly easy to code, you just need to think about the 3 separate forces acting on each node, add them together and divide that by the mass of the node to get the movement of each node.

1. Gravity, put a simple force acting towards the centre of the canvas so the nodes dont launch themselves out of frame
2. Node-Node replusion, You can either use coulombs force (which describes particle-particle repulsion) or use the [gravitational attraction equation](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-physics/chapter/newtons-law-of-universal-gravitation/#:~:text=The%20mathematical%20formula%20for%20gravitational,G%20is%20the%20gravitational%20constant.) and just reverse it
3. Connection Forces, this ones a little tricky, define a connection as 2 nodes and the distance between them.  when the actual distance between them is different from the defined distance, add a force in the direction of the connection multiplied by the difference between the defined and the actual distance

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!